# VueJS children reloading parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue-router project with a parent, child, child setup.

route.js

```
{ path: '/Student', component: Student,
           children: [
               { path: 'CustomTasks', component: CustomTasks,
                children: [
                    { path: ':groupId', name: 'student.task.show', component: SubjectTask },
                ]
               },
           ]
       }
```

Student.vue (**parent**)

```
<router-link to="/Student/CustomTasks"></router-link>

        <div class="w-100">
                <router-view :key="this.$route.params.groupId"></router-view>
        </div>
```

CustomTasks.vue (**1st child**)

```
<router-link to="/Student/CustomTasks/2"></router-link> 
<router-link to="/Student/CustomTasks/3"></router-link>

            <div class="w-100">
                    <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
```

SubjectTask.vue (**2nd child**)

```
<h3 class="col-11">What's New{{ this.$route.params.groupId }}...</h3><br>
```

**Question:** Now they all work but when you click a router-link on 1st Child it **reloads the 1st and 2nd child**! instead of just loading the 2nd child, how do you stop this reloading??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that I had both router-view keys with the same id. Change the names and it worked!

```
<router-view :key="this.$route.params.groupId" :pageName="pagename"></router-view>
<router-view :key="this.$route.params.CustomGroupId" :pageName="pagename"></router-view>
```

Comment: Glad you got something sorted, it is always those annoying little things that get you.

Comment: @Simon Yeah I agree, looked at this far to long to find it was such a small easy error. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that you have two router-view tags.
Usually you would create your template in the app.vue which has the menu and navigation links, and then have the "body" of the page where the router-view goes and any page gets rendered into this area.

the "child" terminology sounds like it is a sub page of the other, which your nested router implies too. However, the components all look separate. Maybe provide a screenshot if you need more detail?

If you are just doing expanding content, pick the first level, show 2nd, pick 2nd show 3rd, then you can probably use v-if or v-show, probably would involve a call to the server to get the data, but hard to comment further without the exact issue, or problem to solve.

Comment: I have now uploaded a picture. I am kind of doing a menu inside a menu. When you click "Custom" it gets data and shows you different "groups" you have access too, Then you can click a "group" to see more about this group.